# Fastest way to find an NSManagedObject in an NSSet

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, nsset

I have 2 NSSets with NSManagedObjects, the objects for each set are fetched in different threads, meaning some have a matching objectID, but the objects themselves are different. Now I want to remove managedObjects in one set from the other.

```
NSSet* oldObjects;
NSMutableSet* currentObjects;

// I want to remove the managedObjects in oldObjects from currentObjects, all objects in oldObjects are also in currentObjects

// This doesn't work, since the objects don't match
[currentObjects removeObjectsInArray:[oldObjects allObjects]]; 

// But strangely enough, this doesn't add any objects to currentObjects, but if the objects don't match, shouldn't it?
//[currentObjects addObjectsFromArray:[oldObjects allObjects]];


// This does work for me but this code is running on the main thread and I can see this becoming rather slow for large data sets
NSArray* oldObjectIDs = [[oldObjects allObjects] valueForKey:@"objectID"];
[currentObjects filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (objectID IN %@)", oldObjectIDs]];
```

Is there a faster way I can filter these out? Would fast enumeration be faster even in this case?

Comment: What kind of objects do you hold in your sets (dictionaries or managed objects)?

Comment: Have you tried: `[currentObjects minusSet:oldObjects]`?

Comment: This has the same result as [currentObjects removeObjectsInArray:[oldObjects allObjects]] I'm afraid

Comment: the innerworkings notwithstanding, but try NSArray *current=[oldObjects valueForKeyPath"@distinctUnionOfObjects"];

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for getting back to with such a delay.

I re-read your question, and now, that I've understood the setting completly I might have a solution for you.

This is not tested, but try something like this:

```
//Since the current objects set has registered its objects in the current context
//lets use that registration to see which of them is contained in the old object set
NSMutableSet* oldRegisteredSet = [NSMutableSet new];
for (NSManagedObject* o in oldObjects) {
    NSManagedObject* regObject = [context objectRegisteredForID:[o objectID]];
    if (regObject) {
        //You could do here instead: [currentObjects removeObject:regObject];
        //You should optimize here after testing performance
        [oldRegisteredSet addObject:regObject];
    }
}

[currentObjects minusSet:oldRegisteredSet];
```